# MySQL Query for " Where SUM(Price) Bigger Than Equal " ?

Tags: php, mysql

This is My Query :

```
SELECT user,name,SUM(price) FROM $tableName WHERE faktor='1' GROUP BY user ORDER BY SUM(price) ASC
```

This Query Work , but i want to Show Who Have Sum(price) Bigger Than 100 $ .
i test it with `WHERE SUM(Price) < '100'` but not work , and Result is wrong.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `HAVING`, not `WHERE`.

```
SELECT user,name,SUM(price)
  FROM $tableName
  WHERE faktor='1'
  GROUP BY user
  HAVING SUM(price) < 100
  ORDER BY SUM(price) ASC
```

`WHERE` applies before doing the group-by. `HAVING` applies afterwords.

Answer (score 2):

To evaluate values from accumulative functions in a query you need to use the [HAVING clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `HAVING`

```
SELECT user,name,SUM(price) FROM $tableName WHERE faktor='1'
GROUP BY user
HAVING SUM(Price) < 100
ORDER BY SUM(price) ASC
```

Comment: Downvoted because the syntax is incorrect, `HAVING` should be *after* the `GROUP BY` clause..

Answer (score 1):

Lookup the `HAVING`-sql clause. It acts as a `WHERE` but is applied to a `GROUP`:

```
SELECT user,name,SUM(price) 
FROM $tableName 
WHERE faktor='1' 
GROUP BY user 
HAVING SUM(price) > 100
ORDER BY SUM(price) ASC
```